# Set Default Close Operation for JDialog

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-platform

I have JDialog class

```
public class NewCCPackageJDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {
public NewCCPackageJDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
      super(parent, modal);
```

Are there default close button in JDialog ,If three is how can I show it.

Comment: No there is no default close button on JDialog you have to make a custom button and put on your dialog

Comment: You might be able to use a JOptionPane. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Jbutton` to the `JDialog`. Set an `ActionListener` on the `JButton`. Call `dispose()` method on your `JDialog` to close it